# python urllib2 {"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}

Tags: python, facebook, urllib2, error-code

I have the below code. If I keep `posts` value as `50` then it works fine, if I make it `200` or bigger then it gives me error:

```
{"error_code":1,"error_msg":"An unknown error occurred"}
```

Is it problem with getting http response or a problem from Facebook server side :

```
import sys
import urllib2
import json

fbpageid = 'cnn'
fb_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
ACC_TOKEN = 'xxx'
fields = 'id,name,likes,talking_about_count,posts.limit(200)'
url = fb_url + fbpageid + "?fields=" + fields + "&access_token=" + ACC_TOKEN
print url
try:
     response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
     contents = error.read()
     print contents
```

Comment: Looks like your request is failing on Facebook's side, probably because you're fetching so many posts - request fewer posts and paginate through the response to get additional pages

Answer (score 0):

Because of timeout of facebook api call it may happen

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/208797482578964